# How do I set the isolation level of all my rails transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using RoR version 4.2.3, and I understand I can set the isolation level of my transactions. However, where do I define setting the isolation level of all transactions? so I only have to define it once and then not worry about it?

I'm using postgreSQL as my database

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583303/how-to-set-a-ruby-on-rails-4-apps-default-db-isolation-level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>There does not seem to be a global isolation option</strike>, thus you are left with four options:

1. Monkeypatch existing `transaction` implementation, so that it picks
   your desired isolation level. (Monkeypatching is not desirable)
2. Use correct `isolation` level throughout your application.

   `SomeModel.transaction(isolation: :read_committed)`
3. Extend `ActiveRecord` and create your own custom transaction method.
4. As commented - you may be able to edit the default isolation level in DB configuration. For postgres it's [this one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-ISOLATION)

Example code:

```
#lib/activerecord_extension.rb
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def custom_transaction
      transaction(isolation: :read_committed) do
        yield
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

Then in your initializers:

```
#config/initializers/activerecord_extension.rb
require "active_record_extension"
```

Afterwards you can use:

```
MyModel.custom_transaction do
  <...>
end
```

And in the future, this will allow you to change the isolation level in one place.

Comment: You can also set the default transaction isolation level for the database server. Edit postgresql.conf; look for default_transaction_isolation. This affects all databases under that server. On the one hand, you can't get much more global than that. On the other hand, changing this setting isn't for most people.

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesn't support setting a global isolation level, but Postgres lets you set one for a session. You can hook into Rails' connection establishment to run a command every time a connection is made, thought the techniques for this all rely on monkeypatching and may be questionable.

- [Run Raw SQL in Rails after connecting to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224331/run-raw-sql-in-rails-after-connecting-to-database)
- [Can I hook into ActiveRecord connection establishment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318873/can-i-hook-into-activerecord-connection-establishment)

Then configure your isolation level with:

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION transaction_mode
```

Though this is interesting, I'd go with something more like [Magnuss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431789/802618) for maintainability and sanity.